# Derivative of numerator greater than denominator implies quotient is increasing.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, power-series, fractions

Let $u, v$ be two non-negative functions satisfying $u'>v'>0$. Then I would like to show $$\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'>0.$$ I'm not sure if this is actually even true, although it is intuitive and has worked for every example that I've tried. Here is my work so far:

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2},
\end{align}
so it remains to show that $u'v-uv'>0$.

We can naively substitute the inequality $u'v-uv'>v'(v-u)$, but I believe $v-u>0$ is not required.

If someone can fill in what I'm missing then I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your result is wrong ; $u(x) = 4 x +5$, $v(x) = 2 x-1$  when $x >0.5$ ; $u' > v'$ everywhere , but this function $\frac{u}{v}$ is not always increasing.

Comment: @Lourrran That's annoying. Is there an extra assumption that would make it work? Because it seems like it works when $u(z)=zf'(z)$ and $v(z)=f(z)$ as defined in the text.

Comment: In other words : If u grows faster than v, u/v can increase or decrease. If u grows proportionnaly faster than v, u/v will increase.

Comment: @Lourrran Happy to accept that as an answer if you write it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try $u(x) = e^{2x}+1$ , $v(x)=e^x$ ; for negative $x$ ($x=-1$ for example), denominator is close to 0, when denominator increases by $0.001$, it is very big, and numerator is close to $1$, when numerator increases by $0.002$ or $0.003$, it is very small (proportionnaly), even if it is more than $0.001$.

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample: $u(x)=2x+1,v(x)=x$. Then $u'=2>1=v'$ but clearly $u(x)/v(x)=2+1/x$ is decreasing in $x$ for $x>0$. Let's think about the intuition here:

---

Suppose you are making $\$200,000$/year and your friend is making $\$50,000$/year. Not bad, right? You're making quadruple what your friend is making!  Now, let's say you got a raise of $\$100,000$/year and your friend got a raise of $\$50,000$/year.  You got a bigger raise, right? But notice you are now making only triple what your friend is making.  Why is that? Because your raise *as a percentage* of your income was smaller than that of your friend.  That is,

$$3={\$200,000+\$100,000\over \$50,000 +\$50,000}={\$200,000\times 150\%\over \$50,000\times 200\%}<{\$200,000\over \$50,000}=4.$$

---

Thus, for a positive ratio to increase, you need the *percent* change in the numerator to exceed the *percent* change in the denominator.  In continuous terms, the derivative of the log of a function captures the percent change in that function per unit change in the independent variable (in the limit as the change in the independent variable vanishes). Thus, for $u,v>0$, we can say $(\log u)'>(\log v)'$, or equivalently $u'/u>v'/v$, guarantees $u/v$ increases.  The quotient rule also shows this since

$$\left({u \over v}\right)'={vu'-uv'\over v^2}=\left({u \over v}\right)\left( {u'\over u}-{v' \over v}\right),$$

or more compactly,

$$(\log (u/v))' =(\log u)'-(\log v').$$